# AHK PixelSearch Loop

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to get my AHK Script to Work.
Basically i want to find a row of x Pixels with the Color 0x26FDFD (BGR). But i don't know the AHK Scripting language well wnough to think about a smart, clean and easy way to program that loop, that the starting point will be modified based on the last found coordinates.

However, here's what i got so far:

```
    SysGet, VirtualWidth, 78
    SysGet, VirtualHeight, 79
    
    ;Farbe nach der gesucht wird:
    ColorVar := 0x26FDFD

    i:=0
    while i < 10
    {
        PixelSearch, FoundX, FoundY, 0, 0, VirtualWidth, VirtualHeight, %ColorVar%, 3, Fast
        if (ErrorLevel = 2)
        {
            MsgBox Could not conduct the search.
            return
        }
        else if (ErrorLevel = 1)
        {
            MsgBox Color could not be found on the screen.
            return
        }
        else
        {
            MouseMove, %FoundX%, %FoundY%
            MsgBox Found a Pixel at %FoundX%x%FoundY%.
            ;return
        }
        
        i++
    }
```

Kinda stupid and basic question, but somehow i can't figure it out.

Comment: Maybe you'd just want to use [ImageSearch](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ImageSearch.htm)?

Comment: i tried, but for a number of reasons i couldn't get it to work stable... so i'll give it a shot with Pixelsearch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to store the X and Y coordinates at the end of each loop, then set the new startpoint accordingly.

here's the code:

```
i:=0
while i < 5
{
    PixelSearch, FoundX, FoundY, startX%A_Index%, startY%A_Index%, VirtualWidth, VirtualHeight, %ColorVar%, 3, Fast
    Switch ErrorLevel
    {
        Case 1:
            MsgBox Website ueberpruefen!
            return
        Case 2:
            MsgBox Makro ueberpruefen!
            return
        Default:            
            MouseMove, %FoundX%, %FoundY%
            ;MsgBox Found a Pixel at %FoundX%x%FoundY%.
            nextLoop := A_Index + 1
            startX%nextLoop% := FoundX + 1
            startY%nextLoop% := FoundY
    }
    
    i++
}
;msgbox % "found 5 matches!, first at: " startX2 "x" startY2
return
```